# Django template tag to truncate text

Tags: django, django-templates

Django has `truncatewords` template tag, which cuts the text at the given word count. But there is nothing like *truncatechars*.

What's the best way to cut the text in the template at given char-length limit?

Answer (score 214, accepted):

This has recently been added in Django 1.4.  e.g.:

```
{{ value|truncatechars:9 }}
```

[See doc here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#truncatechars)

Comment: "truncatechars" is working on latest Django 1.9 also

Answer (score 73):

```
{{ value|slice:"5" }}{% if value|length > 5 %}...{% endif %}
```

**Update**

Since version 1.4, Django have a [built-in template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars) for this:

```
{{ value|truncatechars:9 }}
```

Comment: Since I'm working with pre-1.4 Django, this is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: the [`truncatechars`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars) filter adds an ellipse character by default.

Comment: out of the whole knowledge I have of django I constantly go back to this page to get the trunchated functions that I don't seem to remember when I want to use it, so its only write to comment and put an upvote on the greatest STF post ever ^^

Comment: back for one more ^^

Answer (score 12):

I made my own template filter, that add "..." to the end of (last word of) the (truncated) string as well:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter("truncate_chars")
def truncate_chars(value, max_length):
    if len(value) > max_length:
        truncd_val = value[:max_length]
        if not len(value) == max_length+1 and value[max_length+1] != " ":
            truncd_val = truncd_val[:truncd_val.rfind(" ")]
        return  truncd_val + "..."
    return value
```

Comment: Its default now it django.

Answer (score 12):

If you go on creating your own custom template tag, consider to leverage the native Django util [Truncator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_modules/django/utils/text/).

The following is a sample usage of the Truncator util:

```
>>> from django.utils.text import Truncator
>>> Truncator("Django template tag to truncate text")
<Truncator: <function <lambda> at 0x10ff81b18>>
>>>Truncator("Django template tag to truncate text").words(3)
u'Django template tag...'
Truncator("Django template tag to truncate text").chars(20)
u'Django template t...'
```

And here how you can use it inside a Django template tag:

```
from django import template
from django.utils.text import Truncator

register = template.Library()

@register.filter("custom_truncator")
def custom_truncator(value, max_len, trunc_words=False):
    """ Set trunc_words=True to truncate by words instead of by chars."""
    truncator = Truncator(value)
    return truncator.words(max_len) if trunc_words else truncator.chars(max_len)
```

Eventually you can import the *custom_truncator* in any Django template.

Answer (score 4):

Here it is in the Django Documentation, [Built-in template tags and filters: truncatechars](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#truncatechars)

Answer (score 3):

You should write a custom template filter: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters

Have a look at how `truncatewords` is built in `django.utils.text`

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve your goal with similar code:

`{{ value_of_text|truncatechars:NUM_OF_CHARS_TO_TRUNCATE}}`

where `NUM_OF_CHARS_TO_TRUNCATE` is number of chars to leave.

Answer (score 1):

[`slice`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not quite what I need.

Comment: How so? It can be used to slice strings.

Comment: Documentation says it's for lists. Also it does not append "..." to truncated text.

Comment: It does slice lists. And tuples. And strings. And any Python sequence. Also, adding "..." in the template isn't hard.

Comment: The "..." needs to be added only if it got truncated.

Comment: So then use the `length` filter to check the length.

Comment: This answers the OP's question, and this'll work with older versions of Django. Though with newer versions `truncatechars` should be preferred, due to it being more explicit.

Comment: Understand answer is too old. Now django has builting template tag truncatechars for this

Answer (score 0):

Adding a "truncate" filter was a feature request for 4 years but finally landed in trunk, as far as I understand https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5025 - so we’ve to wait for the next release or use trunk.