# What is the Django filter for truncating characters?

Tags: python, django

On the Django docs for built in tags and filters they give a filter to truncate words but not characters (letters/numbers/spaces, etc). Is there such a thing available?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django template tag to truncate text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235994/django-template-tag-to-truncate-text)

Answer (score 8):

You can use the slice notation: `{{ a_string_variable|slice:":5" }}`
This would give you the first 5 characters in the string.

Comment: very helpful, especially if you want to use something like Django's `truncatechars` without the ellipsis

Answer (score 7):

As of Django 1.4, `truncatechars` is now a built-in filter in the release.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars

Answer (score 0):

I used this before and works fine :

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/194/

Answer (score 0):

It was a feature request for 4 years but finally landed in trunk, as far as I understand https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5025 - so we’ve to wait for the next release or use trunk.