# Truncate Text But in Backward Direction in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I have `myString = "Get the last nine characters of this text, starting with the last one."` and I want to be able to get the last nine characters of in Django template the way I could get the first nine with `{{ myString|truncatechars:9 }}`.

Any idea on how I can get this done?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own filters.

```
@register.filter("truncate_chars")
def truncate_chars(value, max_length):
    if len(value) > max_length:
        #will return last characters if max_length<0
        truncd_val = value[max_length:]
        if not len(value) == max_length+1 and value[max_length+1] != " ":
            truncd_val = truncd_val[:truncd_val.rfind(" ")]
        return  truncd_val + "..."
    return value
```

and then

```
{{ myString|truncate_chars:-9 }}
```

[Look at here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235994/django-template-tag-to-truncate-text)

Comment: {{ myString|truncatechars:9 }} means we want to keep 9 characters and remove all other. Using slice we can remove 9 letter and keep all other. There is a big difference in slice and truncatechars.

Comment: @SavadKP sorry for misunderstood. Please see edited version.